# Determine whether the sequence converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$a_n=\frac {\sin 2n}{1+\sqrt n}$$

This a question from my Calculus Textbook. I tried to solve this by Squeeze Theorem. $$-1\le \sin2n \le 1$$

Then $${\frac {-1}{1+\sqrt n}\le {\frac {\sin2n}{1+\sqrt n}}\le {\frac {1}{1+\sqrt n}}}$$

$\frac {-1}{1+\sqrt n}$ and $\frac {1}{1+\sqrt n}$ goes to zero as $n \to \infty$

so $$0 \le {\frac {\sin2n}{1+\sqrt n}\le 0}$$

Am I doing it right?

Comment: you re thru. . .

Comment: You have it!   Well done.

Comment: Perfect. Now you can have a sandwich (lemma)

Comment: Yes, but you should not write the last line; it is clearly false.

Comment: In the last line, the **limit** is $\ge0$ and $\le0$.

Comment: Yes, I understood. Thank you for pointing it out.