# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin 2n}{1+\sqrt{ n}} $ exist? If it does, what is the value?

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

This question
is inspired by
[Determine whether the sequence converges or diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601506/determine-whether-the-sequence-converges-or-diverges)

Does
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin 2n}{1+\sqrt{ n}}
$$
exist?

If it does,
what is the value?

Wolfy says that
the sum to 10000 terms is
0.198104...
and that
$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \dfrac{e^{2 i n}}{\sqrt{n} + 1} 
= -0.258061 + 0.197808 i
$.
I have no idea
how it got that result.

The Inverse Symbolic Calculator
gives a number of expressions
that are close.
The most interesting is
$.2\sin(24\pi/53)$.

I tried writing

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{m^2-1} \frac{\sin 2n}{1+\sqrt{n}}
=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\frac{\sin 2k}{1+\sqrt{k}}
$$

but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Straightforward from Dirichlet's test: The sum $\sum_{n=1}^N\sin 2n$ can be explicitly computed and bounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**: Consider [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), based on summation by parts. (But who knows what the value is!)

Comment: I should have thought of that.